# Clarification on Canon 188

Tags: catholicism, papacy, canon-law, pope-francis

There is currently controversy between some Catholics regarding the current pope and the validity of him holding the office. On a video addressing this controversy (which I can no longer find), a comment mentioned that some people believed the current pope to be invalid due to Canon 188 in Title IX of the code of the canon law:

Can. 188 A resignation made out of grave fear that is inflicted unjustly or out of malice, substantial error, or simony is invalid by the law itself.

My question is, what exactly is this Canon saying, especially with regards to the "substantial error", and how are people interpreting this to apply to the current pope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Can. 188](https://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/eng/documents/cic_lib1-cann145-196_en.html) A resignation made out of grave fear that is inflicted unjustly or out of malice, substantial error, or simony is invalid by the law itself.

> [Can.188 (Latin)](https://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/latin/documents/cic_liberI_la.html) Renuntiatio ex metu gravi, iniuste incusso, dolo vel errore substantiali aut simoniace facta, ipso iure irrita est.

The English is not as precise as the Latin appears to be, but this canon means that certain acts related to a renunciation (resignation) may render the resignation invalid. The two categories of acts which make a resignation invalid are grave fear and simony. The fear can be a) inflicted unjustly (iniuste incusso), b) from malice (dolo) c) from substantial error (errore substantiali). In Thomistic/Aristotelian ethics, acts done from fear are considered "mixed" voluntary and involuntary. They are involuntary in themselves and voluntary as a means to avoid the feared evil. Hence, fear inflicted, from malice or substantial error implies the act is not what the Pontiff would do otherwise, thus it is invalid.

Substantial error in this case appears to mean if the reigning Pontiff resigns out of fear which is based upon a very erroneous understanding of the circumstances, that resignation is invalid. The qualifier substantial excludes minor error, likely error of a lesser degree that would be unlikely to sway his judgement.

As far as the current Pope, the speculation is likely something to the effect that the late Pope Benedict XVI resigned the Papacy in some similar circumstances, thus his resignation is invalid per this Canon, thus the election of his successor would be invalid (you can't elect a Pope while one is still sitting).